# How to insert and modify string in jquery?

Tags: jquery

This is the string received:
`http://mysite.localhost.com/index.php?option=com_social&view=conversations&id=&Itemid=127`

I need to change it into this:

```
index.php?option=com_social&amp;view=conversations&amp;layout=download&amp;fileid=279&amp;Itemid=127
```

things need to change:

1) add layout=download&fileid=VALUE IN VARIABLE&
2) id change to fileid

I've tried using `url.substr(0, url.indexOf('conversations&'))` to teh first string before the specific string.

Then manually added,

```
permanentlink = url.substr(0, url.indexOf('conversations&')); 
permanentlink+'conversations&layout=download&fileid='+id+'&Itemid=127'
```

But this keeps concatnating the string.. And I'm not sure the correct way of doing this.Can someone help?

Comment: your required string has changed the `&` to `&amp;` is it how you want it? I assumed it was a typo error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing it using regex :

```js
var url = 'http://mysite.localhost.com/index.php?option=com_social&view=conversations&id=&Itemid=127' + '&layout=download';
var newValue = 12222;
var newStr = url.replace(/id=/, 'fileid=' + newValue );
// remove this if doesnt want to replace &
var againNewStr = newStr.replace(/&/g, '&amp;');
alert(againNewStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your can use the [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) api to achieve this:

```
var str = "http://mysite.localhost.com/index.php?option=com_social&view=conversations&id=&Itemid=127";

var url = new URL(str);
var urlParams = url.searchParams;

// add or replace certain keys
urlParams.set('layout', 'download');
urlParams.set('fileid', yourFileId);
urlParams.delete('id');

// the final url
var result = url.toString();
```

But, since this is still rather experimental (especially [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/he/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)) consider using a [polyfill](https://github.com/michael-iglesias/url-api-polyfill).

Answer (score 0):

I would use a split on `&`. So you get a array with all (but one) options. Then you take the first element of the array and split it at `?`. You can look at each option if it is needed and remove or let it inside the array. Then you can add you own options. If everything is ok you can join it and have you url.

(http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp)

(http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_join.asp)

Other approach is a replace with regex. (https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)